# Google App Engine smarty

Tags: php, google-app-engine, smarty

I am using Google App Engine (GAE) for web development and also Smarty html template engine.

As GAE does not support writing files, so I come across this question people raised and I tried out the gs:// which is google bucket for the Smarty template cache files. 
The link below show the solution I am using to place the template cache files.
[smarty and PHP Google Application Engine compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17787266/smarty-and-php-google-application-engine-compatibility)

Hence, I created the bucket and making the cache files created for smarty all in there.

This is my index.php as below.

```
<?php

require 'libs/Smarty.class.php';
 ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

$smarty = new Smarty;

//$smarty->force_compile = true;
//$smarty->debugging = true;


//$smarty->caching = true;
//$smarty->cache_lifetime = 120;


$smarty->assign("Name","Hello");

$smarty->compile_dir= "gs://abctesting.appspot.com/achievotmp/compiled/"; 
$smarty->cache_dir="gs://abctesting.appspot.com/achievotmp/cache/";

$smarty->display('index.tpl');




?>
```

I filled up the app_id (abctesting) and I deployed it up to the server and I hit refresh for the domain name. The first load is working perfectly fine. I could see the desired output but when I hit refresh again and this error show up. 
*Please beware that the app_id is stringly fictional and I am avoiding to let user aware of my app_id due to privacy as I use my full name on it which is very stupid. Sorry for the inconvenience. This is only for development. Once everything is ok and set, I will change the naming again.

Error Shown:

> Warning: include(): gs:// wrapper is disabled in the server
>   configuration by allow_url_include=0 in
>   /base/data/home/apps/s~abctesting/1.376690645530467087/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php
>   on line 160 Warning:
>   include(gs://abctesting.appspot.com/achievotmp/compiled/c0360d049dff10f364dfc53ba2cc3958abf6ee6d.file.index.tpl.php):
>   failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in
>   /base/data/home/apps/s~abctesting/1.376690645530467087/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php
>   on line 160 Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   'gs://abctesting.appspot.com/achievotmp/compiled/c0360d049dff10f364dfc53ba2cc3958abf6ee6d.file.index.tpl.php'
>   for inclusion
>   (include_path='.;/base/data/home/apps/s~abctesting/1.376690645530467087/;/base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk')
>   in
>   /base/data/home/apps/s~abctesting/1.376690645530467087/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php
>   on line 160 Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: Invalid compiled
>   template for 'index.tpl' <-- thrown in
>   /base/data/home/apps/s~abctesting/1.376690645530467087/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php
>   on line 176

This same applied to the localhost development. 
I guess this is the issue where the compiled file is somehow getting some error.

I have search through the internet and the issue raised for the Smarty integration with Google App Engine is quite limited. 
Furthermore, I just wish to use the free quota provided so that I wont have any extra charging on this.
I also read out about the APC extension and some memCache but I didn't try that one yet. It looks complicated as well and I would need guidance on that.

Please help out here as I am really a newbies in this. Is there any workaround for this?

This would be my app.yaml as well..

```
application: abctesting
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /scripts
  static_dir: scripts
  mime_type: text/javascript

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

Please advise and Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: As suggested by the error message, you should put allow_url_include=1 in your php.ini: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#PHP_Directives_with_new_initialization_defaults

Comment: Alright. Let me look into that. Haven't really know how to include php.ini. Thanks anyhow :)

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer to this. 
Firstly, thanks Mars for the tips.

Will need to include the php.ini in the root directive as same as app.yaml.

```
allow_url_include = "1"
google_app_engine.allow_include_gs_buckets = "abctesting.appspot.com/achievotmp/compiled/,abctesting.appspot.com/achievotmp/cache/"
```

I added these two lines into the php.ini and then the error is all gone. I guess previously the allow directory is not allowed.

Hope this helps those who encounter this issue as well.

Thanks .

Comment: When I tried this, Adding the bucket and path didn't work - Smarty could write to, but not read from, the bucket. In the end, I just added the bucket name instead; this worked fine:
google_app_engine.allow_include_gs_buckets = "abctesting.appspot.com"

This could be due to changes in the PHP implementation, or just because I'm using the project's default bucket.

Comment: I created a bucket, but i'm not sure which permissions i need to give to the bucket, so that my app (namely smarty) can write the compiled templates to it. For example, if my app is: my-cool-app@appspot.com, and my bucket is: my-cool-app-smarty-bucket, and i've got: $smarty->compile_dir =  "gs://my-cool-app-smarty-bucket/compiled/"; set in my smarty config, and i've got the php.ini in the root (as suggested) with: allow_url_include = "1", and google_app_engine.allow_include_gs_buckets = "my-cool-app-smarty-bucket/compiled/, why is smarty telling me: Smarty: unable to write file gs://...

Comment: @BenCoffin did you solve this? I have the same issue.

Comment: @james-crowley: I had to put three directives into the php.ini, before it would successfully write the compiled templates to my [Google Storage] bucket. Please note that I did all this in September 2017, so the process might have changed since that time. The three directives are as follows:

allow_url_include = "1";

google_app_engine.allow_include_gs_buckets = "#default#, my-cool-app-smarty-bucket";

google_app_engine.disable_readonly_filesystem = "1";